# How can i use Web view to clear cookies?

Tags: react-native, cookies, axios, webview, expo

I have been using RCTNetworking to clear cookies before every  authentication using axios and it does works and it clear cookies. But from expo 49 does not support or defined RCTNetworking and cannot used this feature to clear cookies.
i have seen i can use webview to clear cookies and add code below as well. But how can i use web view to clear cookies every time i call post function in react native.

```
const Login = (props) => {

 function Post{
    
      const RCTNetworking = require('react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTNetworking');
      RCTNetworking.clearCookies((result) => {
      console.log(result); //true if successfully cleared
        });
        
        axios.post('https://........', {
          auth: {
            username: 'james',
            password: '123456'
          }
        
          }).then(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
        }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        });
        
        }
  
return (
<View>
</View
);

};
export default Login;
```

web view clear cookies

```
<WebView
  incognito={true}
  userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
  source={{
    uri:
      'your url',
  }}
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
/>
```